# Use Ternary operator in Groovy ,Spock and Rest Assured Testing - Intergation Test

Tags: java, testing, groovy, spock, wiremock

I have below code where I want to replace values based on `where` section of the test:

```
void 'should pass some test() {
  given:
  stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/someVal/$productOrderId"))
     .willReturn(defaultWiremockResponse()
       .withBody(""" 
          {
            "startDateTime" : ${myTime? "$myTime" : null}
          }
       """
    )
   //...... some when
   //...... some then
   where:
   productOrderId | myTime
   "1"            | "2023-04-23T07:13:15.862Z"  
   "2"            | "null" 
}
```

This tests works for `null` but gives error for value like `"2023-04-23T07:13:15.862Z"`

> nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries

I think somehow the `"startDateTime"` is not getting the value as wrapped around double quotes `""` and getting as below

```
{
  "startDateTime" : 2023-04-23T07:13:15.862Z   // missing quotes around the value
}
```

and that could be the issue. Can someone help me understand this and fix this error for string interpolation

Comment: no screenshots of plain text please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `\` to handle the double quotes

```
"startDateTime" : ${myTime? "\"${myTime}\"" : null}
```

Comment: This works as aexpected. As an alternative, we can just use `"startDateTime" : ${myTime? '"' + myTime + '"' : null}`, avoiding nested GString interpolation. But both solutions yield `"startDateTime" : "null"` for the `null` case. So if we want `"startDateTime" : null` (unquoted `null` value), we need to change the `where:` block according to Leonard's suggestion, because otherwise `myTime ?` would never evaluate to `null`, as `null != "null"`.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in my comment under *Shashank Vivek*'s answer, you can also do this, avoiding nested GString interpolation altogether:

```java
class MySpec extends Specification {
  def 'should pass some test'() {
    given:
    println \
      """\
      {
        "startDateTime" : ${myTime? '"' + myTime + '"' : null}
      }\
      """.stripIndent()

    expect: true
   
    where:
    productOrderId | myTime
    "1"            | "2023-04-23T07:13:15.862Z"  
    "2"            | null
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
{
  "startDateTime" : "2023-04-23T07:13:15.862Z"
}    
{
  "startDateTime" : null
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxdT7tOwzAU3fMVRxZSWqFWiQO08sLC0gEx0AmxRPEttZQ4kX0DrdL8O7FJpQov9zx87qOqS-_xen7vqAKdmKz2CMQcTFWyaS2GBNB0QOqPbV9rdCHh24bA5DldLOMP4Mt8k1URds5Yri0-IwOEEFc4zHUSPZeOX0qmvWlIQOFuaM4BPyMVKe7xxyYQqILt63qc4-NN67VnZ7qd1WR5sUyiQafpBlZg11MQovhzJEfXDVvdV_zmNLmdxmWeFT2RC9y8C4TMZLHKHlay2GcblRcqf1xvn-SHmBsL-S8RVp2cMRmTX7A6XD4).

Feel free to ignore the backslashes and indentation removal. I was just being precise about avoiding unnecessary indentation and newline characters.